# Android : Capturing HTTP Requests with non-rooted android device

Tags: android, http, http-headers

I have an android application which uses a third party jar in it. 
Http request is sent from third party jar to server when application is running. 
I need to capture HTTP Request that is sent from third party jar. I am wondering if there is an easy way to implement with **non-rooted device**

To start up : 
I tried downloading "proxyDroid" but it need rooted phone
I have also tried downloading "shark for root" with "shark reader" which also need rooted device
I tried many other applications which could capture the complete request but all it need is rooted device

I need something what fiddler/wireshark can do for windows. A network packet analyzer which could be easily integrated with android application that could give request object with all header fields in it.

Comment: Is this your "android application"?

Comment: Yes my android application

Comment: Hello @Venkatesh, did you ever successfully achieve to intercept http requests with non-rooted android?

Comment: @lalalalalala Nope. I could not able to achieve this with non-rooted device.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You could install [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) - an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between their machine and the Internet - on your PC or MAC.

Config steps:

- Let your phone and PC or MAC in a same LAN
- Launch Charles which you installed (default proxy port is 8888)
- Setup your phone's wifi configuration: set the ip of delegate to your PC or MAC's ip, port of delegate to 8888
- Lauch your app in your phone. And monitor http requests on Charles.

Comment: this tutorial worked well: http://jaanus.com/blog/2012/02/12/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with-charles-proxy-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Unfortunately it's a shareware.

Comment: You might want to try alternatively burp suite to get the same job done. It is very powerful and free: https://portswigger.net/burp

Comment: Are there any tool to do the same with web socket traffic? I mean on android itself. (I know wireshark/fiddler for PC)

Comment: What is for Android

Comment: Thank you so much. You make my day.

Comment: You can use Fidler proxy as well. Its free

Answer (score 28):

There are many ways to do that but one of them is [**fiddler**](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

#### Fiddler Configuration

1. Go to options
2. In **HTTPS** tab, enable **Capture HTTPS Connects** and **Decrypt HTTPS traffic**
3. In **Connections** tab, enable **Allow remote computers to connect**
4. Restart fiddler

#### Android Configuration

1. Connect to **same** network
2. Modify network settings
3. Add proxy for connection with your PC's IP address ( or hostname ) and default fiddler's port ( 8888 / you can change that in settings )

Now you can see the full log from your device in fiddler

Also, you can find a full instructions [here](http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler)

Comment: Fiddler beta is available on macOS (relying on mono). This is good news if you don't have a PC.

Comment: Thanks but I mean all computers in this answer. PC / Laptop / etc ... :) @MacKentoch

Answer (score 20):

I just installed Drony. It's not shareware and does not require root on a phone with Android 3.x or above.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandrob.drony

It can intercept and log requests.

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but I want exact sourcode for this app, Can you post a link for source code for android?

Comment: @Smit.Satodia I dont know if they share/publish the source code, if anyone finds it feel free to post the link as a comment

Comment: Source code can be found here: https://github.com/SuppSandroB/sandrop It was originally hosted on Google Code here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/sandrop/

Comment: @JanWytze if you contact the developers maybe they can help you with this.

Comment: it only log hostname/ip, not really useful

Answer (score 19):

It's 2020 now, for the latest solution, you can use Burp Suite to sniffing https traffic without rooting your Android device.

Steps:

1. Install Burp Suite
2. Enable Proxy
3. Import the certification in your Android phone
4. Change you Wifi configuration to listening to proxy
5. Profit!

I wrote the full tutorial and screenshot on how to do it at here: https://www.yodiw.com/monitor-android-network-traffic-with-burp/

Comment: Would be nice to copy the data from the site to you're answer here. Since you're site may go down. Also SO encourages quoting rather than links for this same reason. Other than that great tutorial.

Comment: Although to be fair it may have been better just to improve https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684919/5506988 than to write another "answer".... Anyway great job.

Answer (score 8):

You can use fiddler as webdebugger
  http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-debugging

[Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-debugging) is a debugging tool from telerik software, which helps you to intercept every request that is initiated from your machine.

Answer (score 7):

you can use burp-suite. do follow below procedure.

Configure the Burp Proxy listener

In Burp, go to the “Proxy” tab and then the “Options” tab.In the “Proxy Listeners" section, click the “Add” button.

In the "Binding" tab, in the “Bind to port:” box, enter a port number that is not currently in use, e.g. “8082”.Then select the “All interfaces” option, and click "OK".

Configure your device to use the proxy

In your Android device, go to the“Settings” menu.

If your device is not already connected to the wireless network you are using, then switch the "Wi-Fi" button on, and tap the “Wi-Fi” button to access the "Wi-Fi" menu.

In the "Wi-Fi networks" table, find your network and tap it to bring up the connection menu.

Tap "Connect".If you have configured a password, enter it and continue.

Once you are connected hold down on the network button to bring up the context menu.Tap “Modify network config”.

Ensure that the “Show advanced options” box is ticked.

Change the “Proxy settings” to “Manual” by tapping the button.

Then enter the IP of the computer running Burp into the “Proxy hostname”.Enter the port number configured in the “Proxy Listeners” section earlier, in this example “8082”.Tap "Save".

Test the configuration

In Burp, go to the "Proxy Intercept" tab, and ensure that intercept is “on” (if the button says “Intercept is off" then click it to toggle the interception status).

Open the browser on your Android device and go to an HTTP web page (you can visit an HTTPS web page when you have installed Burp's CA Certificate in your Android device.)

The request should be intercepted in Burp.

Answer (score 4):

Set a https://mitmproxy.org/ as proxy on a same LAN

- Open Source
- Built in python 3
- Installable via pip
- Have a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mitmproxy/mitmproxy)

Comment: They also have a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/mitmproxy/mitmproxy).

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use Genymotion (or another supported emulated device) you can use [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/), which can analyze and intercept/rewrite HTTP calls. For HTTPS you will need a rooted device, to be able to trust the root CA certificate as a system certificate. Genymotion devices are rooted by default.

To install the app you want to investigate, Genymotion supports Open GApps (for Google Play support) and drag-and-drop for APK files.

HTTP Toolkit also works on real devices, but then root privileges are required (most Android phones are not rooted).

https://httptoolkit.tech/docs/guides/android/#intercepting-traffic-from-your-own-android-app

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[SandroProxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy) seems to be better than Drony (by the same developer): You can 
(but do not have to) conveniently view and analyze the traffic in your PC's browser.

Should work in emulators as well.

Comment: Not available in Google Play anymore.

Comment: still available on APKPURE
https://m.apkpure.com/sandroproxy/org.sandroproxy/download?from=details