# Connecting Android App with Database on Remote Server

Tags: php, android, database, cloud

I am trying to access a database which is on a remote server. Database is fine as it works fine with php code, but when I try to add data in that database using android app, data doesn't insert in database.
I have basically followed following tutorials for this purpose

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgOSIEWOXbQ

There are following 2 activities in app

1. Main Activity (Launcher Activity)
   Contains a Button 'Add Contact', clicking on that, 'Add Info' activity opens.
2. [Add Info Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9d65.png)
   Contains 3 Edit Texts and one Button 'Save Data', clicking on that, 'saveInfo' method calls.

public class AddInfo extends Activity {

```
EditText editTextName, editTextEmail, editTextMobile;

String strName, strEmail, strMobile;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_info_layout);

    editTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextMobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);
}

public void saveInfo (View view)
{
    strName = editTextName.getText().toString();
    strEmail = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
    strMobile = editTextMobile.getText().toString();

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(strName, strEmail, strMobile);
    finish();
}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    String add_info_url;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        add_info_url = "sisuol.move.pk/add_info.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name, email, mobile;

        name = params[0];
        email = params[1];
        mobile = params[2];

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(add_info_url);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            String data_string = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("mobile","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(mobile, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return "One row of data inserted!";
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There might be POST issue.
You can use Volley Library.

Add into gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Add JAVA code for post.

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "Your URL",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Do something
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    onLoginFailed();
                }
            }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // Add your Params Here.
                //params.put("email", email);
                //params.put("password",password);

                return params;
            }
    };

    queue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have watched the video you mentioned and considering this assumption that it works fine with PHP code on server-end, my best guess is that client app is not able to do the necessary communication. So, either the communication is not happening at all or it is not sending the parameters correctly. It should be easier for you to dump dummy data in database if there is any kind of request to ensure that at least communication happens successfully. But the more solid approach would be to inspect your network traffic on client side.

Now, for this there are several solutions to debug your application and inspect http traffic. The most latest one is [Stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) which is an open source debugging platform, developed by Facebook, that offers a rich and highly interactive debugging experience to Android developers. But it would require you to do some necessary changes on client side and if you are interested than this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/debugging-android-apps-with-facebooks-stetho--cms-24205) can help you.

Otherwise, if you want to save that time and effort then I would recommend to use [CharlesProxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) tool and this [tutorial](http://jaanus.com/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with-charles-proxy-for-fun-and-profit/) and these basic [config steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685506/1016544) should be very helpful. Charles is basically a web proxy (HTTP Proxy / HTTP Monitor) that you will install on your computer and it will be able to record and display for you all of the data that is sent and received. It will essentially make it easy for you to see the requests, responses and the HTTP headers (which contain the cookies and caching information) between your web browser / client and the server. It can eventually help you in tracking down the problem and fix it.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I'll act according to your suggestions. Lets see what happens. Thank you :)