# Xamarin Forms WebView control programmatically

Tags: web-scraping, xamarin.forms, webview, webbrowser-control

I have a website with form authentication. 
I had successfully logged in that website and read data from it with WebBrowser Control in Windows.Forms.
Hoewever I need to do the same with Xamarin Forms.
Is it possible to control webview in xamarin forms like WebBrowser in Windows.Forms.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that Xamarin.Forms [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview?view=xamarin-forms) do not have a deep object model to automate and achieve the same you do with [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms) control in WinForms, though you can do it in a "blind" way (without UI)...

1. You can trace HTTP trafic with an HTTP monitor to see what happens when a user uses the application:

a. https://www.charlesproxy.com/ (see post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17685506/2117381)

b. https://www.wireshark.org/

2. You can automatize interaction between an application client and a web server via a HTTPclient library, simulating how the user would use the mobile application:

One option... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1

3. You can extract information from HTML with: [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack

This library parses HTML, construcs a DOM.. you can use XPath / XSLt...

I hope this helps