# Generating QR code from Firebase dynamic link not transferring to google store

Tags: android, firebase, qr-code, firebase-dynamic-links

I am generating a QR code from my Firebase dynamic link but when I scan it with an android device's camera I'm transferred to this page -

[image]

Instead of being sent to the google store.

I don't know what exactly is broken... did anybody got this page before? is it a Firebase dynamic link problem? android problem? is it my QR? the scan? is it something I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the url if you scan the QR code with a regular barcode scaner?

Comment: I don't understand the question... the same url as in the picture. which is a valid url, when I copy and paste it to the url line in chrome it's taking me to the google store as it should do when I scan it.

Comment: I would try to [Capture HTTP Requests with non-rooted android device](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17684936/295004) to see if what I'm sending to the server is the same as what is being sent by Chrome. Hidden characters in the url string or server side configuration is my current guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is because dynamic links don't start with "www"